# Why does while loop doesnt work properly for composite simpson's 1/3

Tags: matlab

I have a situation where I have 2 subjects to calculate the composite simpson's 1/3 rule in the while loop, and when error for either one of the subjects become less than 0.001, i have to stop the iteration and prints out the value. I've tried using while loop but i still couldnt get the correct outcome.

```
error = 1; % Jump start
n = 5; % number of points

disp('Integration for Subject 1')
disp('No.pts  Left Comp Simp 1/3  Right Comp Simp 1/3  Left Quad  Right 
Quad')

while error > 0.001
% For left leg
f1 = @(x) s1L(1)*x.^4 + s1L(2)*x.^3 + s1L(3)*x.^2 + s1L(4)*x + s1L(5);
a = valid_time1L(1);
b = valid_time1L(end);
h = (b - a)/(n-1) ;
x = a:h:b;
fx = f1(x);
sum_even = sum(fx(2:2:end-1));
sum_odd = sum(fx(3:2:end-2));

L_simp1 = (h/3)*(f1(a) + 4*sum_even + 2*sum_odd + f1(b));
xTheoL1 = quad(f1,a,b);
error = abs((L_simp1 - xTheoL1)/xTheoL1);


% For right leg
f2 = @(x) s1R(1).*x.^4 + s1R(2).*x.^3 + s1R(3).*x.^2 + s1R(4).*x + s1R(5);
a = valid_time1R(1);
b = valid_time1R(end);
h = (b - a)/(n-1);
x = a:h:b;
fx = f2(x);
sum_even = sum(fx(2:2:end-1));
sum_odd = sum(fx(3:2:end-2));

R_simp1 = (h/3)*(f2(a) + 4*sum_even + 2*sum_odd + f2(b));
xTheoR1 = quad(f2,a,b);
error = abs((R_simp1 - xTheoR1)/xTheoR1);

fprintf('%d \t\t %.4f \t\t\t %.4f \t\t\t %.4f \t 
%.4f\n',n,L_simp1,R_simp1,xTheoL1,xTheoR1)

n = n + 2;
end
```

Comment: Please include the code (or the relevant portion) in your question. Do not link to external images.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If it isn't calculating correctly then it has to do with the functions. The while loop will check error once it reaches the very end of the code. since you have **error** being used for both L and R, it will only evaluate R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big problem with your code is that you don't separate the error for the left and right leg. The while loop will be reevaluated once it reaches the end so if you don't separate the errors, then you will only be evaluating one of them.

```
errorR = 1; % Jump start
errorL = 1; % Jump start
n = 5; % number of points

disp('Integration for Subject 1')
disp('No.pts  Left Comp Simp 1/3  Right Comp Simp 1/3  Left Quad  Right Quad')

while errorR > 0.001 && errorL > 0.001
% For left leg
f1 = @(x) s1L(1)*x.^4 + s1L(2)*x.^3 + s1L(3)*x.^2 + s1L(4)*x + s1L(5);
a = valid_time1L(1);
b = valid_time1L(end);
h = (b - a)/(n-1) ;
x = a:h:b;
fx = f1(x);
sum_even = sum(fx(2:2:end-1));
sum_odd = sum(fx(3:2:end-2));

L_simp1 = (h/3)*(f1(a) + 4*sum_even + 2*sum_odd + f1(b));
xTheoL1 = quad(f1,a,b);
errorL = abs((L_simp1 - xTheoL1)/xTheoL1);


% For right leg
f2 = @(x) s1R(1).*x.^4 + s1R(2).*x.^3 + s1R(3).*x.^2 + s1R(4).*x + s1R(5);
a = valid_time1R(1);
b = valid_time1R(end);
h = (b - a)/(n-1);
x = a:h:b;
fx = f2(x);
sum_even = sum(fx(2:2:end-1));
sum_odd = sum(fx(3:2:end-2));

R_simp1 = (h/3)*(f2(a) + 4*sum_even + 2*sum_odd + f2(b));
xTheoR1 = quad(f2,a,b);
errorR = abs((R_simp1 - xTheoR1)/xTheoR1);

fprintf('%d \t\t %.4f \t\t\t %.4f \t\t\t %.4f \t%.4f\n',n,L_simp1,R_simp1,xTheoL1,xTheoR1)

n = n + 2;
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice and guidance